# jquery-2.1.1.min.js Openwrt Luci

Tags: openwrt, luci

I trying to make my on module for openwrt. I make simple pages for luci and now need for jQuery. So I add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

to my htm file. But browser returns a 404 for `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`.

How to add `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` in luci?

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your router and issue following commands to download *jquery-2.1.1.min.js* at an appropriate location in the web directory of your device.

```
$ cd /www/luci-static/resources
$ wget http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
```

Include the downloaded JQuery source in your HTML file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/luci-static/resources/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

That should do the trick!